# How to set/get a value from another JVM

Tags: java, jvm, code-injection

I have a class `Normal` with the following code:

```
public class Normal {

    private static String myStr = "Not working...";
    private static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(running) {
            System.out.println(myStr);
        }
    }

}
```

And I have another class named `Injector` in another project. Its purpose is to change the values of `Normal` even though they are not in the same JVM:

```
public class Injector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String PID = //Gets PID, which works fine

    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(PID);

    /*
    Set/Get field values for classes in vm?
    */

    }
}
```

What I want to do is change the values `myStr` and `running` in the class `Normal` to `"Working!"` and `false` respectively without changing the code in `Normal` (Only in `Injector`).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you did read [the JavaDocs of VirtualMachine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) and the example there. Your `Injector` can now load an agent (a program already compiled to a separate .jar-file) into the attached JVM.

Comment: The [JavaDocs for the instrument-package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html?is-external=true) contain a lot of information on what an agent needs to work and how to accomplish specific things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two JARs:

1. One is [Java Agent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that uses Reflection to change the field value. Java Agent's main class should have `agentmain` entry point.

   ```
   public static void agentmain(String args, Instrumentation instr) throws Exception {
       Class normalClass = Class.forName("Normal");
       Field myStrField = normalClass.getDeclaredField("myStr");
       myStrField.setAccessible(true);
       myStrField.set(null, "Working!");
   }
   ```

   You'll have to add `MANIFEST.MF` with `Agent-Class` attribute and pack the agent into a jar file.

2. The second one is a utility that uses Dynamic Attach to inject the agent jar into the running VM. Let `pid` be the target Java process ID.

   ```
   import com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine;
   ...

       VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
       try {
           vm.loadAgent(agentJarPath, "");
       } finally {
           vm.detach();
       }
   ```

   A bit more details in [the article](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/JanFeb2017/Default/31/0).